# Howto save Label Text for returning to the page?

Tags: .net, asp.net, detailsview

I want to code something like this:
I have a ListView with some labels (this labels can be increment[+1] and decrement[-1]) by the user via buttons. 
now I have the problem, that each of this list items have a details view at which the user can look at. but when he return to the overview page, all labels are set back to the default 0.

How can I solve this problem, so that the user returns from the details view to the overview, that he see all the changed label values?

Comment: I would save the new values into database when user want to change to DetailsView. You could ask him if changes should be saved. You could save new values immediately after increment also.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to persist values across postbacks then you can use either [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551.aspx) or [Session](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/) to store your data in. It's hard to be more specific without a code example of what you are doing.